# How to replace letter with number?

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, split

I have data frame like below. I would like to replace value of rows with number based on rows 1 and 2. If value in different row (rows have two letter , I like index for each letter)are same with row 1 I like index 1 otherwise 2 and for NA, zero.

Input:

```
                         a1         a2 
      A                   C         T           
      B                   T         C           
    AC11                C/C       C/C
    AC12                C/C       T/C         
    Ac13                C/C        NA
```

output:

```
               a1                 a2
          a1.1  a1.2          a2.1  a2.2
AC11         1     1             2    2
AC12         1     1             1    2
Ac13         1     1             0    0
```

Comment: Is the case always going to be as you described? (i.e. only first 2 rows with the conditions)? thus only 2 possibilities (C/C, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `ifelse` and `sub` to obtain each column of your desired output.

```
ifelse(sub('.*/', '', d$V2[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V2[1], 1, 
        ifelse(sub('.*/', '', d$V2[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V2[2], 2, 0))
#[1] 1 1 1
ifelse(sub('/.*', '', d$V2[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V2[1], 1, 
        ifelse(sub('/.*', '', d$V2[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V2[2], 2, 0))
#[1] 1 1 1
ifelse(sub('.*/', '', d$V3[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V3[1], 1, 
        ifelse(sub('.*/', '', d$V3[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V3[2], 2, 0))
#[1]  2  2 NA
ifelse(sub('/.*', '', d$V3[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V3[1], 1,
        ifelse(sub('/.*', '', d$V3[3:nrow(d)]) == d$V3[2], 2, 0))
#[1]  2  1 NA
```